How can I format these "cases" better?
How can I edit the following fraction, so the "x" is bigger?
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\(\tfrac{x_{\left(\tfrac{n}{2}\right)} + x_{\left(\tfrac{n}{2} + 1\right)}}{2}\)
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please consider providing a compilable minimal working example that contains the document class and packages needed. Only then it is clear to everybody what we are talking about.

You can use \dfrac to enforce LaTeX to use full sized fractions.
I would also encourage you to get rid of the parantheses and maybe even use n/2 instead of \frac{n}{2} when you use fractions in indices (see first case).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    p = \begin{cases}
        \dfrac{x_{n/2} + x_{n/2+1}}{2}, & \text{falls $n$ gerade}\\[1em]
        \dfrac{x_{\frac{n}{2}+1} + x_{\frac{n}{2}+2}}{2}, & \text{falls $n$ ungerade}
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}

This yields:


subscript $n/2 + 1$ is probably less desirable than $1 + n/2$

Similar in some ways to @ttnick's first solution, except that I would place the \frac{1}{2} term ahead of the remaining material.

Would you agree that the version that places \frac{1}{2} ahead of the remaining material is more readable?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}( x_{n/2} + x_{n/2 + 1}) &\text{falls $n$ gerade,}\\[\jot]  % ok 
\frac{x_{n/2} + x_{n/2 + 1}}{2}     &\text{falls $n$ gerade.} % not quite ok
\end{cases}
\]  
\end{document}

